# The population of a village

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The population of a village was $1000$ one year ago. The population at present is $10210$. Find the population growth rate.

My attempt:

Initial Population $(P_0)=1000$
Final Population $(P_n)=10210$
Time $(T)=1$ year
Rate $(R)=?$

Now, 
$$P_n=P_0\left(1+\frac {R}{100}\right)^T$$
$$\frac {1021}{100}=\left(1+\frac {R}{100}\right)$$

But the answer given in my book is $2\%$. Why do the answers not match?

Comment: I suppose one more typo in a textbook ! $10210$ should be $1020$ to get the "answer"

Comment: Is it how many people per month? Per year?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Claude's insight was correct; replacing $10210$ with $1020$ does yield a growth rate of $2\%$.

\begin{align}
P_n&=P_0\left(1+\frac{R}{100}\right)^T \\
\frac{1020}{1000}&=1+\frac{R}{100} \\[0.8ex]
\frac{2}{100}&=\frac{R}{100} \\[0.8ex]
R&=2
\end{align}